# Making a sprite character jump naturally with pyglet and pymunk

Tags: python, game-physics, pyglet, pymunk

This code displays the image `assassin1.png` on a black screen. This image has a pymunk body and shape associated with it. There is also an invisible static pymunk object called `floor` present beneath it. Gravity is induced on the image and it is resting on the invisible floor.

I would like to make my image jump naturally when I press the `UP` key. How can I implement this?

```
import pyglet
import pymunk

def assassin_space(space):
    mass = 91
    radius = 14
    inertia = pymunk.moment_for_circle(mass, 0, radius) 
    body = pymunk.Body(mass, inertia) 
    body.position = 50, 80 
    shape = pymunk.Circle(body, radius) 
    space.add(body, shape) 
    return shape 

def add_static_line(space):
    body = pymunk.Body() 
    body.position = (0,0)
    floor = pymunk.Segment(body, (0, 20), (300, 20), 0)
    space.add_static(floor) 
    return floor

class Assassin(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, batch, img, space):
        self.space = space
        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, img, self.space.body.position.x, self.space.body.position.y)

    def update(self):
        self.x = self.space.body.position.x
        self.y = self.space.body.position.y

class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, width = 315, height = 220)
        self.batch_draw = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.player1 = Assassin(batch = self.batch_draw, img = pyglet.image.load("assassin1.png"), space = assassin_space(space))
        pyglet.clock.schedule(self.update)
        add_static_line(space)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.batch_draw.draw()
        self.player1.draw() 
        space.step(1/50.0) 

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.UP:
            print "The 'UP' key was pressed"

    def update(self, dt):
        self.player1.update()
        space.step(dt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    space = pymunk.Space() #
    space.gravity = (0.0, -900.) #
    window = Game()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply an impulse to the body. Impulse is a change in momentum, which is mass times velocity. I assume you want your asassin to jump straight up. If that is the case, you have to apply the impulse to the center of the body.

```
body.apply_impulse(pymunk.Vec2d(0, 60), (0, 0))
```

Comment: You *always* apply the impulse to the center of the body, whether you want to jump straight up or at an angle. The only time to apply it to somewhere other than the center is if you want the body to spin as well as jump.

Answer (score 3):

Writing a platformer using a physics library like PyMunk is really difficult. I would strongly advise against it, and instead to manage physics like jumping in your own code.

The problem is that realistic physics like pymunk's come with many side effects that you really don't want. For example, when your character is running sideways, they will experience a frictional drag against the floor, which cannot operate through their center of mass, so will tend to make them rotate or fall over. You may find ways to counteract this, but these will have other undesirable side-effects. For example, if you make your character a squat shape with a large flat bottom edge, then this will also affect collision detection. If you reduce their friction with the floor, this will mean they don't slow down over time. You may add still more refinements to correct for these things, but they will have yet more side-effects. The examples I give here are just the tip of the iceberg. There are many more complex effects that will cause big problems.

Instead, it is massively simpler to have a variable representing your character's velocity, and add that to their position every frame. Detect if they have hit anything like a platform, and if so, set their horizontal or vertical velocity such that they do not move into the platform. This also comes with some subtle problems, but they are generally much easier to fix than a physics simulation.